# How to create a table from a drag option table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show a table based on what choice is made from a drop down box.the table will have two columns and the selected value of the table will be the number of rows of the table with additional row for heading of tables

```html
<html>
    <body>
    
        <select name="dropdown" size="1">
        <option selected value="">Please make a selection</option>
        <option value="10">Choice 10</option>
        <option value="8">Choice 8</option>
        <option value="4">Choice 4</option>
        
        </select>
        
        <!--i.e. if Choice 4 is selected I'd like to display a new <tr> with the
        following: -->
        
        <tr>
        <th> Flat No.</th>
        <th>  Floor No.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
         </body>
        </html>
```

The values of the table will be saved in a database after submit.
I want to do this only by using javascript and html but I
can't achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `eventlistener` whenever that specific row is navigated to (using `.selectedIndex`) , then within that `function` you could `appendChild(row)` to the specific table you want to the row to append after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>
    
    
        <select id="myOpt" name="dropdown" size="1">
          <option selected value="">Please make a selection</option>
          <option value="10">Choice 10</option>
          <option value="8">Choice 8</option>
          <option value="4">Choice 4</option>
        </select>
    
        //i.e. if Choice 4 is selected I'd like to display a new <tr> with the
        //following:
     <table id="myTable">
        <thead>    
        <tr>
        <th> Flat No.</th>
        <th>  Floor No.</th>
        </thead>
        </table>
    <br>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var e = document.getElementById("myOpt");
      var opt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      myRows(table,opt);
    }
    
    function myRows(table, opt){
       
      for(var i=0; i<opt; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@kazi asif ahmed reshad

Please try this code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="myOpt" name="dropdown" size="1" onchange="addrow()">
          <option selected value="">Please make a selection</option>
          <option value="10">Choice 10</option>
          <option value="8">Choice 8</option>
          <option value="4">Choice 4</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
     <table id="myTable">
        <thead>    
        <tr>
        <th> Flat No.</th>
        <th>  Floor No.</th>
        </thead>
        </table>
    <br>
    
    <script>
    function addrow() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var e = document.getElementById("myOpt");
      var opt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      myRows(table,opt);
    }
    
    function myRows(table, opt){
      
      for(var i=0; i<opt; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.
Thank you.